# Google maps API Not resizing despite event listener - Created through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, google-maps

I am currently using google maps api to generate a map, and the map is not resizing to the div. Instead, a lot of grey area is occurring and I am hoping someone could help me out here.

Here is the code that generates the map:

```
<div class="map" style='width: 750px; height: 200px;'></div>
```

this div is targeted, and this div is in a partial which is rendered on this ajax request:

```
$(".categorybox2").on('click', function() {
    choice3 = $(this).text();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/result/" + choice1 + "/" + choice2 + "/" + choice3,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "script",
        data: { choice1: choice1,
                choice2: choice2,
                choice3: choice3 },
        complete: function(data) {

            function initialize()
            {
                var arrcount=0
                var arr=$(".hidden").text().split(",")
                for (var i=0; i<=2; i++) {
                  if (i === 0) {
                    arrcount=0
                  } else if (i === 1) {
                    arrcount = 2
                  } else if (i === 2) {
                    arrcount = 4
                  }

                  var mapProp = {
                  center:new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(arr[arrcount]),parseFloat(arr[arrcount+1])),
                  zoom:15,
                  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                  };

                  var myLatlng= (parseFloat(arr[arrcount]),parseFloat(arr[arrcount+1]))
                  var map=new google.maps.Map($(".map")[i]
                    ,mapProp);

                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: mapProp.center,
                    map: map,
                  });

                  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
                     //var center = map.getCenter();

                     //map.setCenter(center);
                     google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                  });



            }
          }

            initialize()
            // for (var i=0; i<=2; i++) {
            //   $($(".map")[i]).css("width", "700")
            //   $($(".map")[i]).css("height", "200")
            // }


        }
    })
```

});

The map initially looks like this:
[image: Map incorrectly loading]

and when you resize the actual window itself, the map changes to this (despite being in the idle state for a long period (only resizing the actually browser window retriggers it to fill in the grey)): 
[image: After browser resize]

and the map should be centered, on the marker, like this:
[image: Correct version]

I have also tried using "bounds_changed" instead of "idle" but have had no luck. Please this is a very annoying problem!:)

Edit:

Here is the entire partial:

```
<% @result.each do |event| %>
  <div class="eachresult">
 <div class="matchscore">
                        Relevance score:
                        <a class="score"><%= event[0].round(1) %>%</a>
                    </div>

                <div class="map" style='width: 750px; height: 200px;'></div>

      </div>
<% end %>
```

The css initially on the div that holds the map (Output):

```
.wrapper .output,
.wrapper .output1,
.wrapper #blackness {
    display: none;
}
```

this is the javascript that triggers the showing of the map:

```
$(".price").on('click', function() {
    $(".price, .question3, .bk2category").fadeOut( function() {


      var black = setTimeout(function() {
        $(".output, .question4, .output1")
          .delay(500)
          .show()
          .animate({left:"+15", opacity: 1}, 1000);
      }, 1000);

      $(".blackness").fadeOut();
      $("#foo").fadeOut("slow")
    });
  });
```

Comment: How many maps do you place to one div? You are using _var map = new google.maps.Map(**$(".map")[i]**, mapProp);_

Comment: Hey @AntoJurković I place each map in their own div. Refer to the edit to look at the entire partial.

Comment: Somehow this makes no sense, the map should be visible completely. Are the div's initially hidden?

Comment: @Dr.Molle the div that holds the maps is initially hidden. I added the css and javascript above. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I figured it out! I noticed the map would not resize until I moved the browser. So I decided to set a delay in the rendering of the map in the javascript. AND now it works!!!

Here is the code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
            initialize()
          }, 3000)
```

Thanks for the help people!:)